# Pass Iterating Object to Controller Method

Tags: ember.js, controller

When trying to pass an iterating object to the Controller method, the object is passed as a String.

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="gradebooks">
  {{#each}}
    {{#link-to "gradebook" this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}
  {{/each}}
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="gradebook">
  <h1>Student Grades</h1>
  {{#each student in students}}
    {{#each assignment in assignments}}
      {{student.name}}, {{assignment.name}}: {{getGrade student assignment}}%
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('gradebooks', function() {
    this.resource('gradebook', { path: ':gradebook_id' });
  })
});

App.GradebooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find(App.Gradebook);
  }
});

App.GradebookRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find(App.Gradebook, params.gradebook_id);
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
App.GradebookController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  getGrade: function(student, assignment) {
    console.log(student, assignment);
    return 5;
  }
});
```

Model:

```
App.Gradebook = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  students: DS.hasMany('student', { async: true}),
  assignments: DS.hasMany('assignment', { async: true})
});
App.Student = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  gradebook: DS.belongsTo('gradebook'),
  grades: DS.hasMany('grade', { async: true })
});
App.Assignment = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  gradebook: DS.belongsTo('gradebook'),
  grades: DS.hasMany('grade', { async: true })
});
App.Grade = DS.Model.extend({
  score: DS.attr('number'),
  student: DS.belongsTo('student'),
  assignment: DS.belongsTo('assignment')
});
```

Currently, the above outputs the string `"student"` for each student. If I were to have `{{getGrade student.id}}`, it would output the string `"student.id"`. How could I get it to pass the student as an object?

Answer (score 0):

Given your revision I've revised my answer below to better align:

```
App.AssignmentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   needs: ["student"],
   getGrade: function() {
      var student = this.get('controllers.student');
      //logic to get grade
   }.property() //thing to observe for changes
});


<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="gradebooks">
  <h1>Student Grades</h1>
  {{#each}}
    {{#link-to "gradebook" this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}
  {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="gradebook">
  {{#each student in students}}
     {{render 'student' student}}
  {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="student">
   {{name}} 
   {{#each assignment in assignments}}
     {{render 'assignment' assignment}}
   {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="assignment">
   {{name}}: {{getGrade}}%
</script>
```

A useful tool is {{log model}} or {{log record}} or {{log ...whatver..}} to understand what data your view is receiving.

If you open the Chrome Ember Inspector you should also see what views, controllers, routes, models, etc. have been defined which will help with understanding.

In short you cannot pass parameters to controllers by using {{getGrade student.id}} - you can define a Handelbars helper to accept parameters but I don't think this is what you are after.  The method above worked for me.

Hope this helps

Comment: Defining it in such a way wouldn't work for me because my full example has both `students` and `grades`. I'll edit my question to show a fuller example.